# Compare Node value to string

Tags: xslt

Below is my XML I want to show all the values of AgentSales if State = Talking Out

```
<AgentSales>
<AgentName>WRIGHT SIMMONS NATHANIEL</AgentName>
<State>Talking Out</State>
<Reason/>
<time>3</time></AgentSales>
```

here is my XSLT

```
    <xsl:if test="/NewDataSet/AgentSales/State[text() = \'Talking Out\']">

  <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="time" order="descending"/> 
  <tr>

     <td><xsl:value-of select="AgentName"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="State"/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="time"/></td>

  </tr>
</xsl:if>
```

This is my error

> Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.

Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to "escape" the apos like `\'Talking Out\'`, just use `'Talking Out'`.

Second, the `xsl:sort` instruction can only be child of `xsl:apply-templates` or `xsl:for-each` instructions in XSLT 1.0

Third, the XSLT style:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="Agents">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="time" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="AgentSales[State='Talking Out']">
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="AgentSales/*">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="AgentSales/Reason|AgentSales"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<Agents>
    <AgentSales>
        <AgentName>WRIGHT SIMMONS NATHANIEL</AgentName>
        <State>Talking Out</State>
        <Reason>whatever</Reason>
        <time>3</time>
    </AgentSales>
    <AgentSales>
        <AgentName>SOMEONE</AgentName>
        <State>Talking In</State>
        <Reason>whatever</Reason>
        <time>2</time>
    </AgentSales>
    <AgentSales>
        <AgentName>SOMEONE ELSE</AgentName>
        <State>Talking Out</State>
        <Reason>whatever</Reason>
        <time>5</time>
    </AgentSales>
</Agents>
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>SOMEONE ELSE</td>
        <td>Talking Out</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>WRIGHT SIMMONS NATHANIEL</td>
        <td>Talking Out</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Dumb question but when I view source shoudl I see the HTML Tags or just the XML nodes?  Because in the browser it looks great I just expected to see the <table> <tr> and <td> tags and I don't.

Comment: @Denoteone: How do yo perform the transformation in browser? An XML document with a PI?

Comment: I echo the value of $style  using php $style contains my XML data as a string.  The data looks good in the browser I just expected to see HMTL tags when I view the source

Comment: @Denoteone: So you perform the transformation server side. Then you should see the HTML output when viewing the source in browser.

Comment: I hate to sound like a noob in XSL but I want to understand what I am doing. So the above style sheet does the following:

Comment: matches the all elements Agents and puts them in a table. Next is says what ever goes in the table sort. Then it says match="AgentSales[State='Talking Out']" and put that data in a <tr>. and in the <tr> put the elements of AgentSales that's state is Talking Out and sort them. what I don't understand is  <xsl:template match="AgentSales/Reason|AgentSales"/>
 what does that do?

Comment: @Denoteone: Four rules: `Agents` rule, output `table` element with the content of applying templates to his children sorted by their `time` child; `AgentSales` with `State` equal to 'Talking Out' rule, output a `tr` and apply templates; `AgentSales` children elements rule, output a `td` with the string value; Empty rule (no output) for `AgentSales` (those not matched by the other rule with more default priority) and `Reason` child of `AgentSales`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the stylesheet you posted: a) you don't need to screen `'` using `\`, just write `'Talking Out'`. b) [`xsl:sort`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp) cannot be a child of `xsl:if`.

Comment: the "\" are in there because this is part of a bigger PHP script. I will take out sort and see what I can get.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:template match="AgentName[../State='Talking Out']">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</xsl:template>
```

**Also**, read a good book on XSLT to get at least the fundamentals: `<xsl:template>`, `<xsl:for-each>`, `<xsl:sort>`, the identity rule and overriding it, ..., etc.

Comment: Thanks I have been spending a lot of time on w3schools but hasnt been much help.

Comment: It's not a good idea to learn XSLT via w3schools. You should better read Michael Kay's books and the specification.